# CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor fails with iOS 7

Tags: ios7, core-graphics, cgcontext

I Use this function to draw a custom UILabel. It works with iOS 6 and earlier but fails with iOS 7. If I replace CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor with CGContextSetFillColorWithColor, it works with iOS7 but not with 6 and earlier.

```
void ShadowedStrokedText(CGContextRef ctx,NSString *text,CGPoint textStartPont,UIColor *textColor,UIFont *font,CGFloat lineWidth,UIColor * shadowColor,CGFloat shadowThickness){

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx,kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, textColor.CGColor);
//---this works with iOS7 
//CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, textColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextStroke);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx,CGSizeMake(0,0),shadowThickness,[shadowColor CGColor]);

[text drawAtPoint:textStartPont withFont:font];

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);}
```

why?

Comment: may be they decrepated that from iOS 7

Comment: I checked. No deprecation, only different behavior. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drawAtPoint:withFont:` which you are using is [deprecated in iOS7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:withFont:):

> `drawAtPoint:withFont:`
>
> Draws the string in a single line at the specified point in the current graphics context using the specified font. **(Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use drawAtPoint:withAttributes: instead.)**